# Cannot display full calendar with Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, fullcalendar

i am trying to add ui-calendar into my project but the calendar is not visible.

I am install ui-calendar with bower and added these depedencies:

```
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.css" />
    <script src="bower_components/moment/moment.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/fullcalendar/dist/fullcalendar.js"></script>
    <script src="bower_components/angular-ui-calendar/src/calendar.js"></script>
```

I follow the example in github and added this div into my html view.

```
<div ui-calendar="uiConfig.calendar" ng-model="eventSources">
```

In my controller, i add the initial config:

```
    $scope.uiConfig = {
  calendar:{
    height: 450,
    editable: true,
    header:{
      left: 'month basicWeek basicDay agendaWeek agendaDay',
      center: 'title',
      right: 'today prev,next'
    },
    dayClick: $scope.alertEventOnClick,
    eventDrop: $scope.alertOnDrop,
    eventResize: $scope.alertOnResize
  }
};
```

I dont have any errors in console but the calendar is not displayed. What i have missing in my code?

Comment: Can you show me your complete angualr app code?

Comment: I have lot of code, i cannot show here but for full calendar, i only add the previous code

Comment: Have you injected 'ui.calendar' in your app?

Comment: Yes, i have injected  'ui.calendar'

Comment: It´s difficult to get an idea with the code you provide us, but maybe you can take a look at this plnkr and compares with you. It has a very basic example of ui-calendar implementation http://plnkr.co/edit/LbVkCo?p=preview

Answer (score 0):

Replace your HTML with

```
<div class="calendar" ng-model="eventSources" 
config="campaignsCalendarConfig" ui-calendar="campaignsCalendarConfig"></div>
```

. U're missing calendar class and configuration.

Comment: Please do not ask questions in your answer post. Any questions you have for the user should be asked through the comments box. You can update your answer post as per the answer the user gives. However, strictly refrain from asking question difectly in your answer post.